# An Easier way to initialize an interface with multiple nested objects Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an interface that has multiple nested objects and I want to have an easier way to initialize them.

currently my interface

```
export interface Order {
  _id: string;
  orderDetails: {
    create_time: string;
    id: string;
    payer: {
      address: {
        country_code: string;
      };
      email_address: string;
      name: {
        given_name: string;
        surname: string;
      };
      payer_id: string;
    };
    purchase_units: [
      {
        amount: {
          value: string;
          currency_code: string;
        };
        payee: {
          email_address: string;
          merchant_id: string;
        };
        shipping: {
          address: {
            address_line_1: string;
            address_line_2: string;
            admin_area_1: string;
            admin_area_2: string;
            country_code: string;
            postal_code: string;
          },
          name: {
            full_name: string
          }
        };
      }
    ]
  };
  products: [
    {
      quantity: number
      _id: string,
      product: {
        _id: string,
        amount: number,
        category: string,
        description: string,
        imageUrls: [],
        title: string,
        userId: string
      }
    }
  ];
  user: {
    name: string,
    userId: string
  };
}
```

and then I receive them like this

```
export class AllOrdersComponent implements OnInit {
  order: Order = {orderDetails: {payer:{name: {} as any}as any} as any} as any;
  id: string;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private adminService: AdminService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params["id"];
      this.adminService.getOrder(this.id)
     .subscribe(orderData => {
       this.order = orderData.order;
     })
    });
  }
}
```

the problem is, if I do not initialize them before doing the http request in the OnInit function then I get an error that `'_co.order.orderDetails'` is undefined.

so  I initialize them as I do at the start of the component, however, it looks very verbose and redundant there must be a prettier and easier way to do this?

Comment: Yes it seems unlikely that this cant be done in a much prettier way, however I dont see `_co.order.orderDetails` used anywhere. Can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem, perhaps on stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the structure of your object. When you are waiting for an asynchronous data, everywhere you want to use it, you have to check if the variable is defined. Don't make yourself an empty object. Keep it undefined before you get the actual data.

So in you HTML, you may use

```
<div *ngIf="order">
  <span>{{ order.orderDetails.payer.email_address }}</span>
</div>
```

Also, while defining your interface, you may create sub-object's interfaces, for lisibility:

```
export interface Order {
  _id: string;
  orderDetails: OrderDetails;
  products: Products[];
  user: User;
}
```

Comment: He could also just turn `order` into an `observable` and then use the `async` pipe in the html.

Comment: Indeed, with the drawback to not be able to use it outside the HTML then.

Comment: That drawback only exists if you can't have user interactions. A simple `(click)="someProcessing(order)"` would get the order into the ts. :)